# Wordpress dashboard : "Sorry you are not allowed to access this page" after moving live website to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, permissions

I tried to backup my Wordpress website manually.

1. I did a backup of my htdocs folder.
2. I exported a .sql file backup of my database which has "mas" as a prefix. (no underscore after)
3. I updated the old URL for the new URL in all my database (using PowerShell).
4. I updated the wp-config.php file.
5. I created a new database with the same name on my localhost server.
6. I imported the .sql file on PhpMyAdmin.

After that, I realized I could not access the dashboard as an administrator.

I had the following message : Désolé, vous n’avez pas l’autorisation d’accéder à cette page.

Which is the French equivalent of : Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

So I deactivated all my plugins.
I changed my .htaccess file for .htaccess.old .

In my database, my table usermeta is configured like this for my user account. For some reason, I have two times "prefix_capabilites" and "prefix_user_level" :

| meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| mascapabilites | a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} |
| masuser_level | 10 |
| wp_capabilities | a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} |
| wp_user_level | 10 |

And then, I tried to debug my website with PHPStorm.

This is what I found :

```
// plugin.php

function user_can_access_admin_page() {
    global $pagenow, $menu, $submenu, $_wp_menu_nopriv, $_wp_submenu_nopriv,
        $plugin_page, $_registered_pages;

    $parent = get_admin_page_parent();

// I omitted some functions here...

if ( empty( $parent ) ) { // $parent is empty ""
        if ( isset( $_wp_menu_nopriv[ $pagenow ] ) ) { // $pagenow is "index.php"
            return false; // It returns here.
        }
```

And then, it returns here :

```
// menu.php

if ( ! user_can_access_admin_page() ) {

    /**
     * Fires when access to an admin page is denied.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'admin_page_access_denied' );

    wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' ), 403 ); // And displays this.
}
```

So, from what I understand, my page index.php is considered TRUE for the table $_wp_menu_nopriv[].

And it somewhat confirms that the user can't access admin page.

But I don't understand what this variable $_wp_menu_nopriv[] means ?

Can you help me?

UPDATE 1:

I tried to change my user wp_capabilites value to :
'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'

But it didn't work either.

And when I try to backup my site with a backup plugin, there is always an error at some point.

UPDATE 2:

I found the solution to my problem from this [website](https://clients.websavers.ca/whmcs/knowledgebase/346/When-I-log-in-to-WordPress-I-canandsharp039t-access-the-dashboard.html).

> This occurs when you have (at some point) changed the database prefix
> using a utility that also altered capability records in the database.
>
> To repair it, make note of your current database prefix. The default
> is 'wp_' and for simplicity we're going to assume the target prefix is
> 'wp_'. If the database prefix you wish to use is different, make sure
> to replace all instances of 'wp_' with your new prefix.
>
> Use phpMyAdmin in Plesk for the database and complete these searches
> (using LIKE %...%):
>
> In the wp_options table, look for the option_name that ends with
> "user_roles" and change its prefix so it reads "wp_user_roles" In the
> wp_usermeta table, look for all entries that begin with the wrong
> prefix and replace the incorrect prefix with wp_ Now login or refresh
> the page and you should find your user permissions have returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem from another [website](https://clients.websavers.ca/whmcs/knowledgebase/346/When-I-log-in-to-WordPress-I-canandsharp039t-access-the-dashboard.html) :

> This occurs when you have (at some point) changed the database prefix
> using a utility that also altered capability records in the database.
>
> To repair it, make note of your current database prefix. The default
> is 'wp_' and for simplicity we're going to assume the target prefix is
> 'wp_'. If the database prefix you wish to use is different, make sure
> to replace all instances of 'wp_' with your new prefix.
>
> Use phpMyAdmin in Plesk for the database and complete these searches
> (using LIKE %...%):
>
> In the wp_options table, look for the option_name that ends with
> "user_roles" and change its prefix so it reads "wp_user_roles" In the
> wp_usermeta table, look for all entries that begin with the wrong
> prefix and replace the incorrect prefix with wp_ Now login or refresh
> the page and you should find your user permissions have returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the wp_capalities

```
update wp_usermeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'
where user_id = YOUR USER ID
and meta_key = 'wp_capabilities';
```

Otherwise you could consider a brand new wordpress install and migrate over using a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gell, I tried your solution, but it did not solve the problem.

And when I tried to use backup plugins, it didn't work either.